# How to Fix Weights of a Trained Model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, visualization, restore

I trained, checked with my validation set that it learned pretty well, and saved the weigths (ckpt) of my DNN and now I would like to "visualize my classes" (like here : https://www.auduno.com/2015/07/29/visualizing-googlenet-classes/.) by "Instead of using backpropagation to optimize the weights, which we do during training, we keep the weights fixed and instead optimize the input pixels."

Is it possible to restore my model as non trainable ?

If not, is there a way to circumvent this and use my model to it anyway ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You cannot restore the model as non traininable, you have to set it up as non-traininable before you call "restore". This can be done by setting `trainable=False` to the weights.

Comment: Mmh .. is there a way to circumvent this ? :/ (I edited my question)

Comment: You do not have to retrain your model. Simply add `trainable=False` before you restore your model and you should be good to go.